# Make apache index.html default instead of wordpress

Tags: apache-http-server, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a server on a CentOS machine that already has apache and wordpress installed on it. I want to view the default apache web page `index.html` when accessing from the browser but it redirects to the default `index.php` of wordpress. Is there any way I can change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress runs on apache. You're likely loading wordpress first since docroot is set to wordpress. You'd want to move the docroot location one level up. This might *potentially* break anything that wordpress has set statically.

That said, *someone* might have set up the system this way for a reason, would know why its like that and you might break it.

Smart thing to do here? If you have a domain for the wordpress instance, set up a virtualhost for it. Then set up a new virtualhost on a different directory for the other thing with a different domain or subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a specific file by using the command:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

If you want to use any file whatsoever as the default page.

If you, however, want to use index.php at any time, you can simply just type it into the URL as such:

http://domain.com/index.php

But any other time if you were to type http://domain.com, it will use the file you gave within the .htaccess with `DirectoryIndex <file.ext>`.